# How to limit width of underline and fix the position to middle?

Tags: css, elementor, underline

I have tried to add an underline to a header of a website I have been developing. This underline works while hovering or active page, the problem is that I could not figure out to center the underline to the text if I change the width property

The website is https://www.faithful-farming.com/

And the code is the following:

```
elementor-item:after {
background-color: #E98B0D !important;
height: 5px;   
content: "";
bottom: 0;  
width: 100%;    
left:0;   
border-radius: 4px;
line-height: 2px;  
}
```

So if I change the width: from 100% to 80%, it is not centered it and is set to the left due to left:0; I tried to use align center but I don't know why is not working.

- Problem: if I change the size, it will not center it.

Comment: Site is irrelevant, and there is nothing to see there related to the problem.

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML and any other relevant CSS. At the moment we don't know what that % width is a percentage of.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to center an element that is less than 100% width, you can not set the left margin to 0. Simply change the width to 80% and the left margin to auto or 10%.

````
background-color: #E98B0D !important;
height: 5px;   
content: "";
bottom: 0;  
width: 80%;    
left:10%;   
border-radius: 4px;
line-height: 2px;  
}```
````

Comment: This work, thank you!! Silly question, but why is 10%?

Comment: 10% represents half of the remaining width (i.e. 100-80=20 divided by 2 equals 10).

Comment: If the answer provided solved your issue, please mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.